# i want to result data to table

Tags: php, loops, codeigniter, fpdf

why fill the table sideways?
I want to go down, help plis :D

[image]

Controller

```
  public function cetak_inbound($id){
  $pdf = new FPDF('L','mm','A4');
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
  $pdf->SetX(60);

  $Y_Fields_Name_position = 15;
  $pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
  $pdf->SetX(10);
  $pdf->Image('http://localhost/race/assets/frontend/img/logo-race.png',10);

  $pdf->ln(30);

  $cetakinb = $this->M_inbound->cetak_inbound($id);
  foreach ($cetakinb->result() as $row){
      $pdf->Cell(40,6,$row->kd_inbound,1,0);
      $pdf->Cell(25,6,$row->tgl_inbound,1,0);
      $pdf->Cell(67,6,$row->reciver_name,1,0); 
  }
  $pdf->Output();
}
```

Model

```
public function cetak_inbound($id){
    $hasil=$this->db->query("SELECT nama_cs,kd_inbound,tgl_inbound,reciver_name,inbound.status FROM inbound INNER JOIN inbound_detail ON inbound.id_inbound=inbound_detail.id_inbound INNER JOIN service ON service.id_service=inbound_detail.id_service INNER JOIN customers ON customers.id_cs=service.id_cs WHERE inbound.id_inbound='$id'");
    return $hasil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add `$pdf->Ln()` on each of the last column like this :

```php
public function cetak_inbound($id){
    $pdf = new FPDF('L','mm','A4');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $pdf->SetX(60);

    $Y_Fields_Name_position = 15;
    $pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
    $pdf->SetX(10);
    $pdf->Image('http://localhost/race/assets/frontend/img/logo-race.png',10);

    $pdf->ln(30);

    $cetakinb = $this->M_inbound->cetak_inbound($id);
    foreach ($cetakinb->result() as $row){
        $pdf->Cell(40,6,$row->kd_inbound,1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(25,6,$row->tgl_inbound,1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(67,6,$row->reciver_name,1,0);
        $pdf->Ln();
    }
    $pdf->Output();
}
```